# dynamically add an array by using jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

In the most of the websites when I see the browser 'view page source', a lot of java-script array or JSON data is populated dynamically. I think this data we can get it from the database and store it in java-script array. Can any one suggest me how to add data dynamically from jQuery ajax call and assign it in array variable..

I tried with `array push()` method. but no luck.

Can any one suggest me how to do it?

Comment: can you post little code of what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: // Your URL,
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var result = data.d; // your json data
            $.each(result , function (index, value) {
                myArray.push([value.property, value.property2]); // push array note `[]`
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: i did the same thing. but actually i am looking for reusability of the json string in multiple controls. i.e initially i call the jqury ajax and push the data into array. the same array i want to utilise throughout the Application (reuse jquery ajax data)

Comment: Then in this case you can declare your array at global scope and then can use the same to push data in ajax success. In this case it will be avaiable globally.